# FTP a text file to a server using VBA in Excel

Tags: ftp, excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet where the user enters certain data, which I want to store in a text file and upload to a server using FTP. One site suggested adding a reference to "Microsoft Internet Transfer Control" and then define an "Inet" object to do the FTP. However, I am unable to find a reference with this name in "Tools -> References" in the VB Editor. Does anyone know of a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution I found by doing some Google search -

```
Public Sub FtpSend()

Dim vPath As String
Dim vFile As String
Dim vFTPServ As String
Dim fNum As Long

vPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
vFile = "YourFile.csv"
vFTPServ = "********"

'Mounting file command for ftp.exe
fNum = FreeFile()
Open vPath & "\FtpComm.txt" For Output As #fNum
Print #1, "user ***** *****" ' your login and password"
Print #1, "cd TargetDir"  'change to dir on server
Print #1, "bin" ' bin or ascii file type to send
Print #1, "put " & vPath & "\" & vFile & " " & vFile ' upload local filename to server file
Print #1, "close" ' close connection
Print #1, "quit" ' Quit ftp program
Close

Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "\FtpComm.txt " & vFTPServ, vbNormalNoFocus

SetAttr vPath & "\FtpComm.txt", vbNormal
Kill vPath & "\FtpComm.txt"

End Sub
```

Original source: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=184692

Comment: Here is a [ShellWait](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0004.htm) function to wrap the Shell call in.  It will wait until the shell command (the ftp function above) finishes before continuing.  Its from an access site but should work for any vba host.