# Excel vba ftp successful but no document on server?

Tags: vba, excel, ftp, excel-2007

I hope you can help me with some code here. I've created a module that creates a ftp command file and then a batch file to execute it.

I got this process from another StackOverflow post:
[FTP a text file to a server using VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914647/ftp-a-text-file-to-a-server-using-vba-in-excel)

Some of the time test.txt shows up on server, most of the time it doesn't. However, ftp prompt always reports successful transfer.

[image: Screenshot of ftp.exe successful transferred.]

```
Private Sub SendFileToServer()
Dim sCmdFile As String
Dim sBatFile As String
Dim vPath As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer

vPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
sCmdFile = vPath & "\" & "ftp" & "\" & "ftpCommand.txt"
iFileNum = FreeFile

  Open sCmdFile For Output As iFileNum
    Print #iFileNum, "open 555.555.555.55"
    Print #iFileNum, "user username"
    Print #iFileNum, "password"
    Print #iFileNum, "hash"
    Print #iFileNum, "ascii"
    Print #iFileNum, "lcd " & vPath
    Print #iFileNum, "cd dsi_Timesheets"
    Print #iFileNum, "put " & vPath & "\" & "test.txt"
    Print #1, "close"
    Print #1, "quit"
  Close #iFileNum

    Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "\ftp" & "\ftpCommand.txt " & vFTPServ,    vbNormalNoFocus
    SetAttr vPath & "\ftp" & "\ftpCommand.txt", vbNormal
    Kill vPath & "\ftp" & "\ftpCommand.txt"
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem: I'm viewing ftp server files using Filezilla.  test.txt wasn't showing up on the ftp server because I was viewing a cached version. By refreshing the ftp directory in Filezilla  every time code runs, text.txt is there.