# Upload via SFTP using Excel VBA code

Tags: php, vba, excel, ftp

I have tried to use the following code, which I found in [a previous SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914647/ftp-a-text-file-to-a-server-using-vba-in-excel) question, to upload a generated .php file to my shared server via FTP.

I am using Excel 2016 on Windows 10, and trying to upload to a server with 1and1.

```
Public Sub FtpSend()

Dim vPath As String
Dim vFile As String
Dim vFTPServ As String
Dim lInt_FreeFile01 As Integer

vPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\UploadFiles\"
vFile = "rd1.php"
vFTPServ = "domain-name.co.uk"

lInt_FreeFile01 = FreeFile

'Mounting file command for ftp.exe
Open vPath & "\FtpComm.txt" For Output As #lInt_FreeFile01
    Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "domain-name.co.uk"
    Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "username"
    Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "password"
    Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "/test/"
    Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "ascii"
    Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "send " & Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\UploadFiles\" & "rd1.php"

    Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "bye"

Close #lInt_FreeFile01

Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "FtpComm.txt " & vFTPServ, vbNormalNoFocus

SetAttr vPath & "FtpComm.txt", vbNormal
Kill vPath & "\FtpComm.txt"

End Sub
```

When I run the macro, there is no feedback as to what has happened, but the file has not been transferred into the /test/ directory on the server. I've tried a number of permutations, but I can't get it to work.

Any advice on how I can get this to work?

On another note, I also tried the code [here](http://www.bygsoftware.com/Excel/VBA/ftp.htm), but couldn't get this to work either...

I have previously used FileZilla to transfer files via FTP, but this Excel workbook is going to be handed out to a number of team members and the ability to upload using Excel VBA code is an important part of streamlining the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "/test/"
```

to

```
Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "cd test"
```

or perhaps

```
Print #lInt_FreeFile01, "cd /test"
```

If you need to set the active directory relative to root.

If that doesn't work, then your issue is in the path you are copying from:

```
Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\UploadFiles\" & "rd1.php"
```

because the rest of your FTP Commands file looks legit.

Comment: Made a few changes, including changing the directory path and your other suggestions, but it's still not working. The screen flickers briefly, but there's no other feedback and when I check the directory on the server, the file has not transferred. Has this code worked for you previously?

Comment: Is it likely to make a difference that I am using SFTP instead of FTP, and if so can I specify this in the code?

Comment: sFTP makes a huge difference. Windows doesn't do sFTP natively. You will need to use WinSCP or PuTTY.

Comment: Got it. I'll set aside some time to explore WinSCP before coming back to this. Thanks very much.

Comment: The PuTTY code is in this post btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457719/upload-with-vba-via-sftp-ftp-log-outputs-to-detect-errors?rq=1